# Why do not CloudTableQuery.Begin/EndExecuteSegmented auto-hande continuation tokens

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using .NET storage client (June 2012) and I have a query like the following

```
(from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<Entity>(tableName)
 select e).AsTableServiceQuery();
```

This returns `CloudTableQuery` type and it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee741713.aspx) as:

> “Converts a query of type `DataServiceQuery` to a `CloudTableQuery` object that handles continuation tokens and retries failed calls to the Table service.”

I have tried to make CloudTableQuery to handle pagination “internally” in table service responses for me. [`Execute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758410.aspx) method does exactly this, handles continuation tokens if there are more results.

On the other hand, when I try to use asynchronous methods for the same operation ([`BeginExecuteSegmented`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff361746.aspx)/[`EndExecuteSegmented`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758484.aspx) pair), I observed that both overloads of [`BeginExecuteSegmented`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff361746.aspx) does not handle pagination internally (as advertised in `AsTableServiceQuery()` docs).

Therefore wrote the following snippet:

```
while (true){
    var ar = continuationToken == null ?
        entities.BeginExecuteSegmented(null, null)
        : entities.BeginExecuteSegmented(continuationToken, null, null);

    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(ar, r => entities.EndExecuteSegmented(r));
    var resultSegment = await task;
    results.AddRange(resultSegment.Results);
    if (resultSegment.HasMoreResults)
    {
        continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
    }
    else { break; }
}
```

This successfully handles pagination but I am trying to understand **why does not `Begin/EndExecuteSegmented` of `CloudTableQuery` handle pagination internally like synchronous equivalent `Execute()` does.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteSegmented only returns a single result segment, which contains entities and a continuation token. Execute, on the other hand, handles continuation internally and will iterate through all result segments.

But you are right that BeginExecute and EndExecute are not there in the Windows Azure Storage Client Library. The reason is simply the definition of IEnumerable. IEnumerable itself is not asynchronous and therefore, the implementation would have to block the caller when it needs to fetch the next result segment, which would not be asynchronous.